# Bitwise operations in C coding

Tags: c, embedded, stm32f4discovery

I'm trying to learn how to write drivers for GPIO pins in STM32F4 Discovery. I was going through the tutorials and I came across this line:

```
static void hal_gpio_configure_pin_mode (GPIO_TypeDef *GPIOx, uint16_t pin_no, uint32_t mode)
{
    GPIOx->MODER |= (mode << (2* pin_no));
}
```

I am relatively new to embedded systems and don't know what `GPIOX->MODER |= (mode << (2* pin_no));` does. Also, I don't know why pin_no is 16 bit while mode is 32 bit. I know that << is the left shift bitwise operator. But I still don't get the complete context.

Can anybody explain all this?

Comment: There is no reason `pin_no` and `mode` should have the same type. Their values are not used together as occurs in operations like add or multiply. Rather, `pin_no` is simply an index, used (with 2) to calculate how much to shift a value (`mode`). The number of bits to shift simply has to be a number; it does not have to be the same type as the thing being shifted. So, while operators like `+` and `*` require that their operands be converted to the same type, the `<<` operator may have different types on its left and right sides.

Comment: Look at the moder register in the gpio section of the documentation for the chip.  You will see that this is simply setting a couple of bits in this register.

Comment: Google: "c how do the bitwise operators work". Or read a book.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trying to explain the line `GPIOx->MODER |= (mode << (2* pin_no));`:

- `GPIOx` is a pointer to a structure
- `GPIOx->MODER` accesses the member `MODER` inside this structure
- `x |= y` is an abbreviation of `x = x | y`, which means "perform a logic OR of x and y, and write the result back to x
- `mode << (2* pin_no)` means left-shift the content of variable `mode` by twice `pin_no` bits.

Hence, the line means "take the content of `GPIOx->MODER`, bitwise-OR it with the left-shiftet content of `mode`.

Comment: I would add to it that it is likely a mode for each pin is encoded by two bits and can have 4 different values. And this function is assuming the mode is initially set to `00`.

Comment: yes fine for post reset depending on the reset state, but should mask off before orring.